# c# write big files to blob sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

I have c# application which writes files to an sqlite database.
It uses entity framework for modelling data.
It converts the file to a `blob` (entity `byte[]` variable) with this line:

```
row.file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file_to_load.FileName); //row.file is type byte[]
                                                               //row is entity class table
```

This works correctly when the file size is less than 300MB.
When the file size is more than 300MB, the app throws an exception:

> **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

How I can write to blob direct, without in-memory variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use so-called [Incremental BLOB I/O](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_open). See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1692/7386.aspx) post on a System.Data.SQLite forum.

Comment: For the curious, this (now expired) link went to [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090601234106/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1692/7386.aspx) but it seems the proposed patch never made it and Incremental Blob IO is still not possible with System.Data.SQLite 1.0.95

Comment: It should be in 1.0.103.0 according to [this timeline](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/timeline?r=blobIo&nd&c=2016-07-01+09%3A06%3A52&n=200)